# Type "in" is not assignable to type 'ExpressionName' TS Error in Mapbox Project

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

In a TypeScript Project, I am trying to use **lookup** Expression of Mapbox and trying to initiate a private variable.

But getting a TS Error  of Type '"in"' is not assignable to type 'ExpressionName'.

Attaching Screenshot[image]

Also, "in" lookup key is missing in latest type declaration file's of version 1.10.2
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mapbox-gl

Attaching Screenshot:

[image]

However, There official documentation say's lookup "in" key is valid expression:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#lookup

Can anyone suggest how to handle this situation in TS project, However final JS compilation of code is working fine?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but it looks like you're not using `in` correctly. It should have two arguments, something like `["in", ["get", "seatId"], seatIds]`.

Comment: Hey Steve, I have tried that way also, but still, my problem is not resolved. Just a quick question, why declaration files of mapbox-gl has missing lookup attributes. What I can see there are 4 lookup(but not 'in')
        | 'at'
        | 'get'
        | 'has'
        | 'length'
Attaching link: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts

Comment: Sounds like you have lots of different questions. Suggest you do some more reading and resarch and experimenting, and  when you get stuck, raise one question that shows the issue you're having and what you've tried.

Comment: Hi Steve, Its the same question, resolving one will solve our main question. As I said in my previous comment, missing 'in' key in type declaration file, make's typescript through an error.  If i try to use other lookup value's like 'at' | 'get' | 'has' | 'length'. (which do exists in declaration file's) Everything get's fine. Hope I am able to express my intention here.